# How to implement membership functions using Express & MySQL and JWT

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, jwt

I currently implemented login and membership functions using Express & MySQL.

And I want to add JWT.

I wanted to create an API only through Postman, not on the Web, and I heard that I had to use Passport to search.

And I know there is also Express-generate, but I want to modify my current code.

I am a beginner in Node.js and want a guide.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var static = require('serve-static');
var path = require('path');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');

var expressErrorHandler = require('express-error-handler');

var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit:10,
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'password',
    database:'test',
    debug:false
});

var app = express();

app.set('port', 3000);

app.use('/public', static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
    secret:'my key',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized:true
}));

var router = express.Router();

router.route('/process/login').post(function(req, res) {
    console.log('/process/login');

    var paramId = req.body.id;
    var paramPassword = req.body.password;
    console.log('request parameter:' + paramId + paramPassword);

    authUser(paramId, paramPassword, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error');
            res.writeHead(200, '{"Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8"}');
            res.write('<h1>error</h1>');
            red.end();
            return;
        }

        if (rows) {
            console.dir(rows);

            res.writeHead(200, '{"Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8"}');
            res.write('<h1>user login success</h1>');
            res.write('<div><p>user:' + rows[0].id + ' </p></div>');
            res.end();
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, '{"Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8"}');
            res.write('<h1>user not found</h1>');
            res.end();
        }
    });
});

router.route('/process/adduser').post(function(req, res) {
    console.log('/process/adduser');

    var paramId = req.body.id;
    var paramPassword = req.body.password;

    console.log('request parameter' + paramId + paramPassword);

    addUser(paramId, paramPassword, function(err, addedUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error');
            res.writeHead(200, '{"Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8"}');
            res.write('<h1>error</h1>');
            red.end();
            return;
        }

        if (addedUser) {
            console.dir(addedUser);

            res.writeHead(200, '{"Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8"}');
            res.write('<h1>user added</h1>');
            res.end();
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, '{"Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8"}');
            res.write('<h1>user added fail</h1>');
            res.end();
        }
    });
})


app.use('/', router);

var addUser = function(id, password, callback) {
    console.log('addUser');

    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
        if(err) {
            if (conn) {
                conn.release();
            }

            callback(err, null);
            return;
        }
        console.log('db threadid' + conn.threadId);

        var data = {id:id, password:password};
        var exec = conn.query('insert into users set ?', data, 
        function(err , result) {
            conn.release();
            console.log('SQL syntax' + exec.sql);

            if (err) {
                console.log('SQL error;');
                callback(err, null);
                return;
            }

            callback(null, result);
        });
    });
};

var authUser = function(id, password, callback) {
    console.log('authUser' + id + password);

    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            if (conn) {
                conn.release();
            }

            callback(err, null);
            return;
        }
        console.log('db threadid:'+ conn.threadId);
        var tablename = 'users';
        var columns = ['id'];
        var exec = conn.query('select ?? from ?? where id = ? and password = ?', [columns, tablename, id, password],
        function(err, rows) {
            conn.release();
            console.log('SQL syntax' + exec.sql);

            if (err) {
                callback(err, null);
                return;
            }

            if (rows.length >0 ) {
                console.log('user find');
                callback(null, rows);
            } else {
                console.log('user not found');
                callback(null, null);
            }
        });
    });

};

var errorHandler = expressErrorHandler({
    static: {
        '404' : './public/404.html'
    }
});

app.use(expressErrorHandler.httpError(404));
app.use(errorHandler);

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('server start' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @yori If you want to create an API, first I will recommend parsing your data as JSON objects and thus eliminating all HTML tags in your code.

In order to use JWT for authentication, you will have to install the jsonwebtoken package as part of your project dependencies: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

I will recommend following the in-depth instructions in this post as a guide: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52

For scope though, here is some explanation:

Express can be used to build robust APIs which can be made available for consumption. POSTMAN is a GUI tool that developers use to query APIs. curl commands is the terminal alternative. JWT is a safe way of representating claims transfered between two parties. I see the need to break down these terms to you so that you will understand the need, relevance and difference between each tool.

Following the guide in the article you will have to refactor your code a little bit.